# How to resolve "Your Google account is not currently enabled for this operation"

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We have a web application developed in PHP (Yii Framework) and we have used Google Cloud storage service for storing files. We have an issue in accessing the files. We got the error saying,

> Your Google account is not currently enabled for this operation.
>   Please check https://console.developers.google.com/billing to see if
>   you have a past due balance or if the credit card (or other payment
>   mechanism) on your account is expired. You can find additional
>   information at https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/signup.

We have service account credentials for authorization with us containing following properties

```
 "type": "service_account"
 "project_id": "project_id"
 "private_key_id": "private_key_id"
 "private_key": "private_key"
 "client_email": "client_email"
 "client_id": "client_id"
```

but we could not find Google account credentials used under which the Service account credentials are created.

Comment: The account details (e.g. a Gmail address) might be in your app configuration. If not, are you sure that no-one in your organisation would at least have the account name? You may have to create a new Google account if you really have lost the credentials (and if you have no way to go through a reset password process).

Comment: There is nothing in app configuration related to Cloud storage except service account credentials. Also, I did not find anyone whose account is used for the storage service. We need files to be accessible in anyhow. Can we get account name at least, it will be much helpful.

Comment: I would suggest you talk to Google and see what they can do for you. If you pay for your services then perhaps that would be sufficient proof of ID for them to reset your account credentials.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can only be handled by a technical support department.

Comment: Thank you @halfer . We also tried to find out the account details with "gsutil" tool. We could authorize with service account credentials and see the list of buckets and its contents. But we could not find the Google account associated with the project.

Comment: You can contact them here and give them the details of you problem https://cloud.google.com/support/